# Why is ReSharper's cleanup code option unavailable?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

When using ReSharper in Visual Studio, I often cannot run the "code cleanup" option, as it is grayed out in the menu. I have also tried using the hotkey but I get the error message: The key combination (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>) is bound to command (`ReSharper_CleanupCode`) which is not currently available.

I've done a lot of research about it online and found that often the reason this option is not allowed is that the file I am working on has not been added to the solution explorer.

If I add the JavaScript file I'm working on to the solution explorer, it then allows me to code cleanup, but this is EXTREMELY inconvenient for me; I open many files in my work and I do not want to make a new project/solution, then manually add the file each time to use this ReSharper feature. (also by adding files to the solution explorer, the files stop saving and I have to manually copy/paste the code from them into the original document when I'm done working with them.)

Is there a setting in ReSharper that I can change to allow me to code cleanup my currently selected file under all circumstances without needing to add it to the solution manual first?

If not, is there a way to configure or utilize Visual Studio 2015 in such a way that allows me to easily add JavaScript/CSS/HTML files to Visual Studio and also to the solution explorer when I don't have a solution/project already created and loaded? (and also actually save the file when I'm done working on it to where I dragged/dropped it from, rather than embedded in a solution file (`.sln`)?) (Currently, Visual Studio DOES save files with CTRL + S, but ONLY if it has not been added to a solution/project. It's currently how I'm editing all of my files.)

Comment: I have the same issue but only with select cs files which is really odd.

Comment: I found that with the c# files if they have the `// <auto-generated>` tag at the top resharper won't format them

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is quite old, but I encountered this in VS2017 with Resharper 2018.1.2.
The only "workaround" I found was to Suspend Resharper, then Resume it.

> Tools -> Options -> Resharper Ultimate -> General -> Suspend Now

Then in the same menu

Resume Now.